# Giving owner permissions to www-data: is it a security risk?

Tags: 18.04, permissions, nginx, chown

I have a small website running on a VPS. I'm using `Nginx` as a web server (a simple `LEMP` configuration). But now i have a problem: i have a small php script that needs to be able to write a log every once in a while...and for that to work i've given owner permissions to `www-data` over `/var/www/html/` after i ren `chmod -R 755 /var/www/html` as `root`. But once i gave owner permissions to www-data user over `/var/www/html/` and i was, obviously, able to run that php script which has to write some logs i started to ask myself: isn't this going to be a HUGE security issue?

So, is making `www-data` the owner of `/var/www/html/` a security issue?

If yes, can you tell me why and what's to be done about it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, is making www-data the owner of `/var/www/html/` a security issue?

No. You can also use "group" `www-data`.

But this is ...

> chmod -R 755 /var/www/html

Generally you need 2 commands: 1 for directories and 1 for files.
Setting every file to executable is bad. You should use this:

```
find /var/www/html -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 750
find /var/www/html -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 640
```

- execute permissions for directory.
- read permissions for files.
- No permissions for others (if there is a flaw in the design of the website this is what will alarm you with errors in `access.log`).

If you really need your script to be executed you set THAT script itself and not the whole website.

You can also use `php-cli` (or `php-cgi` if it is cgi) to execute a php script from command line without the need to set the script itself executable.

Comment: Thank you so much! Are there any good resources for me to use if i want to learn more about permissions and stuff?